# A call for a more granular tag management for users (tag groups)

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Every user is having **"Watched tags"** and **"Ignored tags"**. This is an important core feature of SO because the watched tags are also influencing the feed displayed to the user in the frontpage (please correct me if this is wrong).

Recently I have noticed that this system does not satisfy my needs very well because I see a lot of questions from tags which I am only interested in a little bit at the moment. I would like to have a seperation between favorite tags, tags which I have expertise in, tags which I am simply interested in and tags which I want to ignore (this is already available).

So my suggestion is:

> We introduce tag groups such that a user can group his tags and show not only tag feeds but also tag group feeds

If this is too complicated we could at least give the possibility to distinguish between favorite tags, watched tags, ignored tags and one optional custom labelled tag box.

Note that this feature request would not harm any existing functionality. Every new user still would start with the two default tag boxes in the sidebar and the same way it is kept for existing users. Nothing would change until you activate this functionality within your profile settings.

What do you think about adding this functionality? IMHO it would be really useful.

Comment: "*I would like to have a seperation between favorite tags, tags which I have expertise in, tags which I am simply interested in and tags which I want to ignore (this is already available).*" What would be the difference between "favorite tags" and tags "I am simply interested in"? What different behavior would you want out of that? And why do you need a list of tags that you have expertise on as separate from the rest?

Comment: @NicolBolas Because in my opinion it would be useful. I could see feeds depending on my current interests and I could filter.

If you cannot see a difference for you thats fine. This is also why I primarily suggested to introduce generic tag groups such that each an everybody can decide on its own.

Answer (score 4):

You will essentially be able to do everything you want with [Custom Question Lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179), when saved lists are introduced:

> [image]

If you look at the tabs in the picture, there is a "Javascript & jQuery" list and a "Bounties" list. Similarly, more lists, with specific tags or matching specific criteria or sorted a specific way, will be able to be added.

The feature hasn't been released to actually do this yet but it's apparently in the works. You will need to opt into CQLs in your profile settings, and you can find instructions on how to do so in the link above.